# Approximating high-dimensional integrals by low-dimensional ones

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fa.functional-analysis, na.numerical-analysis

This question is motivated by the following naive one: suppose we have a nice subset $X$ of some Euclidean space, say a polyhedron, and a nice $\mathbb{R}$-valued function $f$ on this subset, say a polynomial. Is it possible to deduce the value of the integral of $f$ along $X$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure from the integrals of $f$ along sets of arbitrarily small Hausdorff dimension? One way to make this precise is as follows.

Let $A_t,0< t\leq 1$ be the subset of $[0,1]$ obtained from $[0,1]$ by first removing the middle $1-t$ part, then removing the middle $1-t$ parts of the resulting two segments, then removing the middle $1-t$ parts of the resulting four segments and so on. (The middle $1-t$ part of a segment $[a,b]$ is the open interval of length $(1-t)(b-a)$ with center $\frac{b-a}{2}$.) Here are some remarks:

1. If $t=\frac{2}{3}$, then $A_t$ is the Cantor middle third set.
2. The Hausdorff dimension of $A_t$ is $\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 2-\ln t}$.

Now let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be some ``nice'' function. Set $g(t)$ to be the average of $f$ over $A_t$. Recall that if $A$ is a compact metric space and $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then the average of $f$ over $A$ is the limit as $i\to \infty$ of the averages of $f$ over $B_i$ where $(B_i)$ is a sequence of finite sets that converges to $A$ in the Hausdorff metric; recall also that the Hausdorff distance between two closed nonempty $A',A''\subset A$ is $$max(min_{a\in A'}dist (a,A''),min_{a\in A''}dist (a,A')).$$

Is it possible to explicitly compute $g(t)$, say when $f(x)=x^n$ with $n$ a non-negative integer? If not, what can one say about this function? Is it analytic in $t$? If so, does it extend analytically to $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$?

[upd: I would also be happy with answers to the same questions for $f(x)=e^{nx}$ or $e^{inx}, n\in\mathbb{Z}$.]

Comment: As you undoubtedly know, Monte Carlo/Las Vegas integration speaks to the randomized version of this problem.

Comment: Steve -- the way I understand it, Monte Carlo integration computes the integral straight away, as the limit of a sequence of expectations. I was interested to know how one can express, in a simple example, a 1-dimensional integral in terms of lower dimensional integrals.

Comment: Perhaps the following AMS Notices article will be helpful? http://www.ams.org/notices/200511/fea-sloan.pdf

Comment: jc -- thanks! This is quite an interesting article (although it does not seem to directly address the question of the posting).

Comment: If X is very nice, perhaps you can utilize Gaussian quadrature?  For example, in a fixed interval of $\mathbb{R}$, by sampling n special points one can compute exactly the integrals of all polynomials of degree <2n.  It seems like this might be generalizable to, say, rectangular regions in higher dimensions; it is computationally infeasible to do this in high dimensions, though, as it would require an absurd number of samplings.  That is ultimately why Monte Carlo methods are used to do integrations in $\mathbb{R}^100$

Comment: Peter -- that's exactly the problem: I don't know how to compute the averages of polynomials (or any other functions) along $A_t$'s in the first place.

Comment: The uniform measure on $A_t$ is a countable convolution of distributions with 2-point support, so it's easy to integrate exponentials if you're willing to accept answers like $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \bigl((\exp(2s/3^n)+1)/2 \bigr)$ for the integral of $\exp sx$ on the Cantor set.  In particular you can get such product formulas for Fourier components.  You can also integrate $x^k$ by differentiating $k$ times and taking $s=0$, though the resulting formulas do get complicated as $k$ grows.

Comment: Noam -- thanks! I would be perfectly happy with answers of that form, or with integrating exponentials instead of polynomials but I was wondering if you could elaborate a little. In particular, how does the integral depend on $t$?

Comment: @algori: For the generalized Cantor set where at the $n$-th stage you keep only $2^n$ intervals of length $r^n$ (for some positive $r \leq 1/2$), the $n$-th factor in the product is $\left(\exp((r^{n-1}-r^n)s)+1\right)/2$.  [Cantor is $r=1/3$; the full interval is $r=1/2$ — check that the product then gives $(e^s-1)/s$ as it should.]  It looks like your $t$ is $2r$, so you can take $r=t/2$ in the resulting product.

Comment: Noam -- thanks again! Could you give an idea or reference as to why the resulting product is equal $\int_{A_t}e^{sx}d\mu_t$ (with $\mu_t$ the $\dim A_t$-dimensional Hausdorff measure)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to average $e^{sx}$ over $A_t$.  Let $r = t/2$, so at the $N$-th step of the construction of $A_t$ we have the disjoint union $A_t^{(N)}$ of $2^N$ intervals of length $r^N$ whose left endpoints are $\sum_{n=1}^N (r^{n-1}-r^n) \phantom. \epsilon_n$ with each $\epsilon_n \in \lbrace0,1\rbrace$.  Thus to choose uniformly at random from $A_t^{(N)}$ we choose for each $n=1,2,\ldots,N$ either $0$ or $r^{n-1}-r^n$ with probability $1/2$, sum these $n$ terms, and add a real number chosen uniformly at random from $[0,r^N]$.  This is a convolution of $N$ discrete measures and a single continuous one, so the average of $e^{sx}$ over $A_t^{(N)}$ is the product of $N$ finite sums and one integral:
$$
\prod_{n=1}^N \frac{1+\exp((r^{n-1}-r^n)s)}{2} \cdot \frac1{r^N} \int_0^{r^N} e^{sx} dx \phantom. .
$$
letting $N \rightarrow \infty$ we find that the average of $e^{sx}$ over $A_t$ is
$$
I_s(r) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1+\exp((r^{n-1}-r^n)s)}{2} \phantom. .
$$
(Check: for $r=0$ this is just $(1+e^{s})/2$ because $A_0 = \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$; and for $r=1/2$ it's $(e^{sx}-1)/s$ because $A_1$ is the interval $[0,1$].)

To average polynomials over $A_t$, it is enough to average $x^k$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$.
To compute these averages we expand $I_s(r)$ in a power series about $s=0$.  It's easier to do this with the logarithm:
$$
\log I_s(r) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \phantom. \log\frac{1+\exp((r^{n-1}-r^n)s)}{2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \phantom. \lambda((r^{n-1}-r^n)s),
$$
where
$$
\lambda(z) := \log \frac{1+e^z}{2} = \frac{z}{2} + \frac{z^2}{8} - \frac{z^4} {192} + \frac{z^6}{2880} - \frac{17z^8} {645120} + - \cdots.
$$
Thus the $s$ coefficient of $\log I_s(r)$ is
$\frac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (r^{n-1} - r^n) = 1/2$; the $s^2$ coefficient is
$\frac18 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (r^{n-1} - r^n)^2 = \frac18 (1-r)/(1+r)$; the $s^4$ coefficient is $-\frac1{192} (1-r)^3 / (1+r+r^2+r^3)$; and the $s^3$, $s^5$, $s^7$, ... coefficients vanish.  So
$$
I_s(r) = \exp\left( \frac{s}{2} \phantom. + \phantom. \frac{1-r}{1+r} \frac{s^2}{8} \phantom. - \phantom.\frac{(1-r)^3}{1+r+r^2+r^3} \frac{s^4}{192} \phantom.+\phantom. O(s^6) \right).
$$
From this we may recover the average of $x^k$ over $A_t$ by extracting the $s^k$ coefficient and multiplying by $k!$.  If I did this right, the average comes to $1/2$ for $k=1$ (of course), then $1/(2+t)$ for $k=2$, and
$$
\frac{4-t}{8+4t}, \phantom{\infty}
\frac{8+2t^2-t^3}{(2+t)^2(4+t^2)},\phantom{\infty}
\frac{(4-t)(4+2t^2-t^3)}{(2+t)^2(4+t^2)}
$$
for $k=3,4,5$.  I did at least check that for $t=1$ we recover $1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,1/6$, and for $t=0$ each average is $1/2$.

Comment: Dear Noam -- thanks a lot for transforming your comments into an answer. So it turns out that the averages of polynomials are in fact rational functions in $t$. That's quite a surprise.